# Prevent reshowing initial slides when displaying multiple slides at once

Tags: jssor

I have my jssor slider set up to display 3 slides at a time similar to [this example](http://www.jssor.com/demos/carousel-slider.html).  It works great, but let's say I have 4 slides.  I want the first page of slides to have the first three slides and the second page to only contain the 4th slide as such (1  2  3) (4      ).  Instead, the second page loops and includes the initial 2 slides (1  2  3) (4  1  2).

Is there a way to prevent the first two slides from being included in the second page?  My initial thought is to create blank dummy slides that fill up space that would otherwise be occupied by the first 2 slides, but I was hoping there was a line in the javascript I was missing.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine your 4 slides to 2 slides. (1 2 3) -> (1) and (4) -> (2)

See following example code,

```
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 606px; height: 150px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div>
            <img src="1.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 200px; height: 150px; />
            <img src="2.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 203px; width: 200px; height: 150px; />
            <img src="3.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 406px; width: 200px; height: 150px; />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="4.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 200px; height: 150px; />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  I'll just have to use some javascript to adjust the number of images in each slide when the window changes size